# how do you create a call using the ATASK api in java to get the milestones, issues and tasks for a Project

Tags: java, api, attask

I can get the Project details from ATTASK api in Java.  I need to get the milestones, issues and tasks for the project using Java API. 
for projects I used

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("groupID", user.getString("homeGroupID"));
JSONArray results = client.search("proj", map);
```

I've tried replacing "proj" with "miles" and "milestone" but no luck..

Comment: Tried "MILE"... No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default AtTask Java API Client you can also pass in a list of fields you would like to see returned from the API.

An example:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("groupID", user.getString("homeGroupID"));

client.search("proj", map, new String[]{"issues:*", "tasks:*", "milestonePath:*"})
```

This will return all projects with a groupID matching the users homeGroupID and each project will contain all issues, tasks, and milestone paths for you to view or loop through.

This website, http://developers.attask.com/api-docs/, could also be a resource to learn more about the AtTask API.